# where to include session.invalidate() code

Tags: jsp, servlets

in my jsp pages i have logout button. when i click it should i call a servlet and include session.invalidate() code or call a jsp and include this code or include the code in every jsp page where i have the logout button.

**logout.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%

        session.invalidate();
        response.sendRedirect("index.html");
    %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>logout</title>
    <%     
    response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache,no-store,private,must-revalidate,max-stale=0,post-check=0,pre-check=0"); 
    response.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
    response.addDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
    %>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's up to you. Where do you want to put it? There is no single answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just have a single logout page.And you could have a logout button on every page of your web application.But once you click on the logout button from any page you should get redirected to your logout.jsp file.

yOU could make a header and footer page.Here you could add your logout button.And you could include this page on every other jsp page where you require the logout button instead of writing logout button code on every page.